# Specifying Column Name As A Parameter in SELECT statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to do something like this, but it always fails with 'Error converting data type varchar to int':

```
DECLARE @intParam INT
DECLARE @ColName VARCHAR(64)

SET @ColName='intcolumn'

SET @intParam = SELECT @ColName FROM myTable
```

How do I accomplish something like this? I can see the problem is that the SELECT statement simply returns the column name as a string, but I am not sure how to fix that. I am using SQL Server 2008R2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use dynamic sql:

- build your dynamic SQL query (take a look at @SQL variable in sample below)
- use output parameter to get value back from dynamic sql (take a look at @intParam and @intParam_out in sample below)
- execute dynamic sql using [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)

```
DECLARE @intParam INT
DECLARE @ColName VARCHAR(64)

SET @ColName='intcolumn'

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(1000)
SET @SQL = 'SELECT @intParam_out = ' + @ColName + ' FROM myTable'
exec sp_executesql @SQL, N'@intParam_out int OUTPUT', @intParam_out = @intParam OUTPUT
```

Answer (score -2):

Use [Cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx):

```
SET @intParam = SELECT cast(@ColName as int) FROM myTable
```

Comment: You misunderstood the question. `'intcolumn'` was a placeholder name of a column.