# Parameter as Column Name in Reporting Service Project

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services

I'm having trouble passing a parameter as a field name in a visual studio reporting service project.  Here is my SQL Statement:

```
SELECT cast(SUM(@Month) as numeric(36,2))
FROM v_financials
WHERE GMOBJ_Object_Account > 0 AND GMOBJ_Object_Account < 100
AND
GMCO_Company LIKE '%' + @Company + '%'
AND
GBLT_Ledger_Type LIKE '%' + @LedgerType + '%'
AND
GMR001_Bill_Item_Code LIKE '%' + @BillItemCode + '%' 
AND
MCRP01_Division LIKE '%' + @Division + '%'
AND
GBFY_Fiscal_Year LIKE '%' + @FiscalYear + '%'
```

The @Month is the part that is giving me trouble.  I keep getting an error that SUM cannot be applied to nvarchar.  I don't understand why I am getting this error because when I pass the field name it runs properly, which is also a string.

Comment: The problem is that you can't use a variable as the column name unless you are using dynamic SQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I said on a comment, you can't use a variable directly as a column name on SQL (In this case, you can't do `SUM(@Month)` unless you want to sum the value of that variable). You can either use dynamic SQL or construct a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT cast(SUM(CASE @Month WHEN 'January' THEN January
                WHEN 'February' THEN February.....) as numeric(36,2))
FROM v_financials
WHERE GMOBJ_Object_Account > 0 AND GMOBJ_Object_Account < 100
AND
GMCO_Company LIKE '%' + @Company + '%'
AND
GBLT_Ledger_Type LIKE '%' + @LedgerType + '%'
AND
GMR001_Bill_Item_Code LIKE '%' + @BillItemCode + '%' 
AND
MCRP01_Division LIKE '%' + @Division + '%'
AND
GBFY_Fiscal_Year LIKE '%' + @FiscalYear + '%'
```

I'm assuming the values for `@Month` and the column names (You need to finish the `CASE` for all the values).

Answer (score 0):

Here is example on how you need to write your query and how you execute it

[Specifying Column Name As A Parameter in SELECT statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8176485/specifying-column-name-as-a-parameter-in-select-statement)

Comment: Thanks so much.  I wasn't sure if this is applicable to the Create a Query in Visual Studio Reporting Services.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i solved the problem: the query is for an INFORMIX database:

```
SELECT * FROM vs_mant_expendedoras_01 
WHERE 
(CASE ? WHEN 'cardman' THEN cardman WHEN 'display' THEN display WHEN 'unit' THEN unit END)  = ?
AND fecha BETWEEN ? AND ?
ORDER BY date;
```

The Report parameter is 'text' kind with available values especified like this:

[image]
Wich gives me a nice Combo picker as the above picture shows.