# SQL - Help me Select the result of concatenating two variables in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, stored-procedures, string-concatenation

I am trying to concatenate two variables in a stored procedure in order to use the resulting string in a SELECT statement. The concatenation works as desired, but upon execution the table does not fill correctly. Here's the code:

```
Create Procedure CurrencyParameter
    @Trade NVARCHAR (5),
    @Target NVARCHAR (5)
AS
    SELECT  
        CONCAT(@Trade, '_', SUBSTRING(@Target, CHARINDEX('U', @Target) + 1, LEN(@Target)))
    FROM 
        Trade_Ratios


EXECUTE CurrencyParameter @Trade = 'CU1', @Target ='CU10';
```

Here is the result
[image]
and here is the desired result
[image]

As you can see, the table fills with the correct amount of rows, but simply replaces the data with the concatenated string. Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: Give us some sample data from Trade_Ratios table.

Comment: You can go through the post :-
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8176485/specifying-column-name-as-a-parameter-in-select-statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8176485/specifying-column-name-as-a-parameter-in-select-statement)

Comment: Another example at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985842/mysql-concat-to-create-column-names-to-be-used-in-a-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need dynamic sql

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Currencyparameter (@Trade  NVARCHAR (5),
                                    @Target NVARCHAR (5))
AS
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(8000)= ''

      SET @sql = Concat('SELECT ', @Trade, '_', Substring(@Target, Charindex( 'U', @Target) + 1, Len(@Target)), ' FROM Trade_Ratios')

      EXEC (@sql)
  END
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Really appreciate your help!

Comment: One more question: How do we select another field along with the concatenated field?